# Не могу задать матрицу из чисел от 1 до 1000 по порядку

Tags: javascript, массивы, матрицы

Суть в том, что нужно создать матрицу из чисел от 1 до 1000 по порядку 
То есть:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16
```

```
function matrArr(rows, columns) {
const arr = [];
// arr[0][0] = 0; 

for (const i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Array();
    for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] + 1;
    }
  }
return arr;
}
```

на выходе получаеться матрица из NaN, задать arr[0][0] = 0 не даёт.
Есть ли какой-то способ создать матрицу из чисел от 1 до 1000 по порядку?

Comment: Перед циклом - `let num = 1;`, в цикле - `arr[i][j] = num++;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function matrArr(rows, columns) {
   const arr = new Array();
   let counter = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Array();
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = counter++;
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(matrArr(10,10))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо ^^
Работает

Answer (score 1):

```js
// аргументы функции: строк, столбцов, начало_отсчета
function matrArr(rows, columns, start = 0) {
  const arr = new Array(rows);  
  let i, j; 
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Array(columns); 
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      arr[i][j] = i * columns + j + start;  // такое выражение - для наглядности (как формировать число только из значений счетчиков). В данном случае, конечно, можно просто " = start++;"
  }
  return arr;
}

let output = document.getElementById('output'), 
    frm = document.getElementById('frm'); 
frm.run.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  output.textContent = ''; 
  let rows = parseInt(frm.rows.value) || 1, 
      cols = parseInt(frm.cols.value) || 1, 
      result = matrArr(rows, cols, 1); 
  result.forEach(r => output.textContent += r.join('\t') + '\n'); 
});
```

```css
* { font: 16px sans-serif; }
input { width: 80px; }
#frm {
  display: flex; width: 350px; 
  justify-content: space-between; 
}
#output { font: 12px monospace; tab-size: 5; }
```

```html
<form id="frm">
  <label>Столбцов: <input name="cols" type="number" value="10"></label>
  <label>Строк: <input name="rows" type="number" value="100"></label>
  <button name="run">Сгенерировать</button>
</form>
<hr>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Объявление массива через `const` допустимо (и в данном случае, уместно), а вот счетчики цикла должны быть переменными :)

Comment: Большое спасибо ^^